# how to use a synchronized linked hash map correctly

Tags: java, dictionary, synchronized, linkedhashmap

trying to make an lru map by subclassing linked hash map.

the map is run through collections.synchronized.

all usages of the map are surrounded by a synchronized block. the unit test also fails if they are all removed. one would think they are not necessary since the map was run through collections.synchronized.

one thread puts sequential numbers (0,1,2,3 ...) into the map. removals are handled by removed eldest entry. no one else removes entries from the map.

the other thread gets the data from the map.

the following unit test fails usually at "oops". this is when a non zero number shows up in the first position (it should be zero until the map gets full). other strange things can happen like null values in the entry set.

any pointers will be appreciated.

thanks

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
class LruMap<K,V> extends LinkedHashMap<K,V> {
    public LruMap() {
        super(defaultMaxSize+1,.75f,true);
        maxSize=defaultMaxSize;
    }
    public LruMap(int arg0) {
        super(arg0+1,.75f,true);
        maxSize=arg0;
    }
    public LruMap(int arg0,float arg1) {
        super(arg0+1,arg1,true);
        maxSize=arg0;
    }
    public LruMap(int arg0,float arg1,boolean arg2) {
        super(arg0+1,arg1,arg2);
        if(!arg2)
            throw new RuntimeException("you did not construct an lru map!");
        maxSize=arg0;
    }
    public LruMap(Map<K,V> arg0) {
        super(arg0);
        throw new RuntimeException("you did not construct an lru map!");
    }
    public boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K,V> eldest) {
        return size()>maxSize;
    }
    public final int maxSize;
    public static final int defaultMaxSize=2048;
    static final long serialVersionUID=0;
}
class Server implements Runnable {
    public Server(final int pieces,final int period) {
        this.pieces=pieces;
        this.period=period;
        lruMap=Collections.synchronizedMap(new LruMap<Long,Long>(3*pieces/2));
    }
    @Override public void run() {
        t0=System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(piece<stopAtPiece) {
            final long dt=System.currentTimeMillis()-t0;
            final long target=piece(dt);
            System.out.println("adding "+(target-piece+1)+" items");
            for(;piece<=target;piece++) {
                synchronized(lruMap) {
                    lruMap.put(piece,piece);
                }
            }
            checkMap(piece,true);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    Map.Entry<Long,Long>[] checkMap(final long n,boolean print) {
        synchronized(lruMap) {
            Map.Entry<Long,Long>[] entries=null;
            if(lruMap.size()>0) {
                final Set<Map.Entry<Long,Long>> entrySet=lruMap.entrySet();
                entries=new Map.Entry[entrySet.size()];
                entrySet.toArray(entries);
                long first=entries[0].getKey();
                long last=entries[entries.length-1].getKey();
                if(print)
                    for(Map.Entry<Long,Long> entry:entries)
                        System.out.print(entry.getKey()+" ");
                System.out.println();
                if(n<pieces&&first!=0) {
                    System.out.println("lru: first!=0! "+first);
                    if(throwWhenfirstIsNotZero) { throw new RuntimeException("oops"); }
                }
                for(int i=0;i<entries.length-1;i++) {
                    long p0=entries[i].getKey();
                    long p1=entries[i+1].getKey();
                    if(p0>p1)
                        System.out.println("out of order! "+p0+" "+p1);
                    else if(p0==p1)
                        System.out.println("dupicate "+p0+" "+p1);
                    else if(p0+1==p1)
                        ; // ok
                    else if(p0+1<p1)
                        System.out.println("skipped "+p0+" "+p1);
                    else System.out.println("some case i mssed!");
                }
            }
            return entries;
        }
    }
    public long piece(final long dt) {
        return dt/period*pieces+dt%period*pieces/period;
    }
    public boolean throwWhenfirstIsNotZero=true;
    protected long piece;
    public long t0;
    protected long stopAtPiece=Long.MAX_VALUE;
    public final int period;
    public final int pieces;
    public final Map<Long,Long> lruMap;
}
public class ServerTestCase {
    @Before public void setUp() throws Exception {}
    @After public void tearDown() throws Exception {}
    @Test public void testRun() {
        server.stopAtPiece=server.pieces;
        server.throwWhenfirstIsNotZero=true;
        Thread thread=new Thread(server);
        thread.setName("server");
        thread.start();
        while(thread.isAlive()) {
            for(long i=0;i<server.piece;i++)
                synchronized(server.lruMap) {
                    server.lruMap.get(i);
                }
        }
    }
    final int period=2*1000;
    final int serverPieces=100;
    Server server=new Server(serverPieces,period);
}
```

Comment: Does your program run in single threaded mode? (replace `thread.start();` by `server.run()`) Also, your loop in the main thread checks `i<server.piece` without synchronization and `server.piece` is not volatile. There could be a visibility problem there (not usre if that would cause your problem).

Comment: the app will have two or more threads. the server runs forever, so replacing thread.start by server.run does not help. making piece volatile does not help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing the collection inside a `synchronized(lruMap)` block, then you probably don't want to wrap it in `Collections.synchronizedMap()` - use one or the other. This is because they will probably be using different locks - in fact it's almost certain, because it's extremely unlikely that `synchronizedMap()` is using `synchronized(this)` internally.

Also I recommend [enter link description here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601)

Comment: No dude.  You _must_ get a synchronization lock on synchronized maps when iterating over them.

Comment: Indeed you must. But my point is that then other accesses to the map must also use the same lock, which is not the lock used by the convenience wrapper.

Comment: He's using the approach specified in the javadoc.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)

Comment: The `LinkedHashMap` javadoc itself also suggests using `Collections.synchronizedMap()`.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html